# Taking in a list of prices, reducing and summing it all up

Tags: c, loops

So I got stuck in a while loop.

I cant use arrays.

I gotta take in a list of numbers(float/double),(assuming the first number is positive and represents a store item price) if the next number is negative, i gotta reduce the old price from the sum and add the new price which is the old price minus the percent(negative number) and then store it in sum.

I kinda got lost while trying to logic it out and
would appreciate any help.

I'm using C.

This is what I got so far:

```
int main() {
  float factor = 0, avgPrice = 0, sum = 0, productPrice = 0, temp = 0;
  int productCount = 0;
  printf("Enter a positive factor: ");
  scanf("%f", &factor);
  while (factor < 0.0001) {
    printf("Invalid factor. Please enter again: ");
    scanf("%f", &factor);
  }
  printf("Enter the list of products in the shopping cart: ");
  scanf("%f", &productPrice);
  if (productPrice <= 0) {
    printf("Error! Invalid input.");
    return 1;
  }
  sum = productPrice;
  productCount++;
  float sumCopy = 0;
  float priceDeduction = 0;
  temp = productPrice;
  while (scanf("%f", &productPrice) != 0) {
    if (productPrice == 0) {
      break;
    }
    sumCopy = sum;

    if (productPrice < 0) {
      sum -= temp;
      priceDeduction = (temp * productPrice) / 100;
      temp -= priceDeduction;
      sum += temp;
    }
    if (productPrice > 0) {
      productCount++;
      sum += productPrice;
      temp = productPrice;
    }
  }
  printf("Final payment: %.2f", sum);
}
```

Comment: Start by editing your post to fix the indention.

Comment: If you are stuck in this loop `while(scanf("%f",&productPrice)!=0)` please explain your thinking behind the condition. Refer to the descruption of the return value https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: What input was used?

Comment: Hey, if the solution to the question was useful then indicate it so or if you have found the answer to your question then please mention It . Stackoverflow is like an encyclopedia. Many people use it and someone else might have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly then you want to find the total price. I don't get why you have written a Scanf statement in while and what is factor. Its not being used anywhere else

I am writing a solution to the statement above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
   char ch = 'N';
   int p, sp;
   int sum = 0;
   do
   {
      printf("Enter the product price: ");
      scanf("%d", &p);
      if (p > 0)
      {
         //temp = productPrice;
         sum += p;
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Please enter a valid first product price.\n");
         break;
      }
      printf("Enter the second product price: ");
      scanf("%d", &sp);
      if (sp > 0)
      {
         sum += sp;
      }
      else if (sp < 0)
      {
         sum += sp;
     
      }
      printf("\nAre you done with the list of products to buy? enter Y or N ");
      scanf(" %c", &ch);
   }while(ch == 'N');
   printf("The final payment is %d ", sum);
}
```